# C++ same object, different results each time

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, object-oriented-analysis

The following is a runnable snippet of my project. It suppose of be a calculator, but I've simplified it to be as simple as possible, while still exhibiting the bug and being functional.

I apologize for bad formatting, style and all else bad about this code `:(` in advance. Some is just to save space here, like blank lines.

#### Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Expression.h"
#include "ArithmeticExpression.h"
using namespace std;
int main() {
    Expression *expr = new ArithmeticExpression("1+2+3", true);
    expr->print();
    delete expr;        // Very intresting, if you don't delete it won't have the problem
    expr = new ArithmeticExpression("1+2+3", true);
    expr->print();
    delete expr;       // bug goes away if you don't delete
    expr = new ArithmeticExpression("1+2+3", true);
    expr->print();
    delete expr;       // ...
}
```

#### Expression.h

```
#ifndef EXPRESSION_H
#define EXPRESSION_H
#include <string>
int findOpIndex(std::string);
int evalLen(std::string);
class Expression {
    public:
        Expression() { }
        virtual ~Expression() { }
        float result;
        std::string resultStr;
        virtual std::string evaluate() { }
        virtual void print() { }
};
#endif
```

#### ArithmeticExpression.h

```
#ifndef ArithmeticExpression_H                                                            
#define ArithmeticExpression_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Expression.h"
class ArithmeticExpression : public Expression {
    protected:
        bool isTopExpr;
        bool isValue;
        Expression *arithExpr;
        Expression *left;
        Expression *right;
    public:
        ArithmeticExpression() { } 
        ArithmeticExpression(std::string, bool);
        ~ArithmeticExpression();
        std::string evaluate();
        void print();
        float convert(std::string);
};
#endif
```

#### Addition.h

```
#ifndef Addition_H                                                                        
#define Addition_H
#include <string>
#include "Expression.h"
#include "ArithmeticExpression.h"
class Addition : public ArithmeticExpression { 
    protected:
        Expression *left;
        Expression *right;
    public:
        Addition(std::string, std::string);
        ~Addition();
        std::string evaluate();
        void print();
};      
#endif
```

#### Expression.cpp

```
#include <iostream>                                                                       
#include <string>
#include "Expression.h"
int findOpIndex(std::string expr) {
    char curChar;
    int bflag = 0;
    int firstOp = -1; 
    for (unsigned int c=expr.length(); c>0; c--) {
        curChar = expr[c];
        if (curChar == '(') {
            bflag++;
        } else if (curChar == ')') {
            bflag--;
        } else if (bflag == 0) {
            if (firstOp != -1) {
                if (curChar == '+' || curChar == '-') {
                    return c;
                }
            } else if (curChar == '*' || curChar == '/') {
                firstOp = c;
            } else if (curChar == '+' || curChar == '-') {
                return c;
            }
        }
    }   
    return firstOp;
}

int evalLen(std::string eval) {
    int count = 0;
    for (unsigned int c=0; c<eval.length(); c++) {
        if (eval[c] != '.') count++;
        else break;
    }   
    return count+3;
}
```

#### ArithmeticExpression.cpp

```
#include <stdlib.h>                                                                       
#include <iostream>
#include "Expression.h"
#include "ArithmeticExpression.h"
#include "Addition.h"
ArithmeticExpression::ArithmeticExpression(std::string expr, bool isTopExpr) {
    this->isTopExpr = isTopExpr;
    int opIndex = findOpIndex(expr);
    resultStr = expr;
    if (opIndex == -1 || (opIndex == -1 && expr[0] == '-' && expr[1] != '(')) {
        isValue = true;
        arithExpr = NULL;
    } else {
        std::string leftExpr = expr.substr(0, opIndex);
        std::string rightExpr = expr.substr(opIndex+1, expr.length());
        arithExpr = new Addition(leftExpr, rightExpr);
    }
}
ArithmeticExpression::~ArithmeticExpression() {
    delete arithExpr;
}
std::string ArithmeticExpression::evaluate() {
    if (isValue) {
        return resultStr;
    } else {
        return arithExpr->evaluate();
    }
}
void ArithmeticExpression::print() {
    if (isTopExpr && isValue) {
        std::string eval = evaluate();
        std::cout << eval << " = " << eval << std::endl;
    } else if (isTopExpr) {
        std::string eval = evaluate();
        arithExpr->print();
        std:: cout << " = " << eval.substr(0,evalLen(eval)) << std::endl;
    } else {
        if (isValue) {
            std::string eval = evaluate();
            if (eval[0] == '-') std::cout << "(" << eval << ")";
            else std::cout << evaluate();
        } else {
            arithExpr->print();
        }
    }
}
float ArithmeticExpression::convert(std::string s) {
    return atof(s.c_str());
}
```

#### Addition.cpp

```
#include <iostream>                                                                       
#include <string>
#include "Addition.h"
#include "ArithmeticExpression.h"
Addition::Addition(std::string leftStr, std::string rightStr) {
    left = new ArithmeticExpression(leftStr, false);
    right = new ArithmeticExpression(rightStr, false);
}   
Addition::~Addition() {
    delete left;
    delete right; 
}
std::string Addition::evaluate() {
    float l = convert(left->evaluate());
    float r = convert(right->evaluate());
    r = convert(right->evaluate());
    r = convert(right->evaluate());
    return std::to_string(l+r);
}
void Addition::print() {
    std::cout << "(";
    left->print();
    std::cout << "+";
    right->print();
    std::cout << ")";
}
```

#### OUTPUT WHEN I RAN IT

```
((1+2)+3) = 6.00
(1+2+3) = 4.00        // This evaluates correctly to 6.00 if 
(1+2+3) = 4.00        //   I don't delete the expr pointer in Main.cpp
```

These values should all be the same. What's wrong?
I didn't use copy constructors; I did write it, but I realized they were never called.
Valgrind confirms, all memory is freed and destructors do their job correctly.

```
    ==20337== HEAP SUMMARY:
==20337==     in use at exit: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==20337==   total heap usage: 22 allocs, 21 frees, 74,480 bytes allocated
==20337== 
==20337== LEAK SUMMARY:
==20337==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20337==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20337==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20337==    still reachable: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==20337==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20337== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==20337== 
==20337== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==20337== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==20337== ERROR SUMMARY: 18 errors from 11 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

The `72,704 bytes in 1 blocks` is a bug in either compiler or valgrind. Not a problem in this code, because I've ran "hello world" and it still says same thing.

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`). Then **use the debugger** (`gdb`) and `valgrind`. Off-topic here, we won't do your homework

Comment: What operating system are you using? Some implementations of C++ on some versions of MacOSX are known to have some memory leaks (at least as reported by `valgrind` )

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I understand you won't do my homework. But I'm looking for guidance in what Im doing wrong. I'll try and read the output of the compiler, but having someone look at it who knows more will be very helpful.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Linux 64 bit, g++

Comment: Learn to use the debugger. In particular, breakpoints and watchpoints in `gdb` are extremely helpful. The "still reachable" valgrind message is not an issue

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Perhaps, you can explain why the problem goes away when I don't `delete expr`. I've updated the question, look at Main.cpp

Comment: Your problem is mostly that your code is giving incorrect results since `(1+2+3)` should evaluate to 6. Fix that first. Use the debugger to run your program step by step and find out what is wrong. Check that you are parsing correctly and building the right [Abstract Syntax Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) then that you are evaluating it correctly

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch The code works, but it only works the first time the object is created or if I don't delete the object in the heap. Which is the confusing part. The code evaluates it correctly, as you can see in the first output.

Comment: **your code** obviously **don't work** as intended since it does not answer 6 for `(1+2+3)`. BTW for such a small project a single header file would be enough (no need to have one header per class in C++)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thank you for the suggestion. New to C++, appreciate it. As MikeCAT pointed out, the problem was a single line, failing to set a variable to false.

Comment: you should learn how to debug... Im guessing you are in school , it's the best time to do it.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch:  I think "we won't do your homework for you" is very harsh.  He has written some code, and found a problem.  He has then gone to the trouble of creating a MCVE.  He just needs someone to get him past the mental block of "it works the first time".

Comment: @francium: Having said all that, you should have been able to debug this.  If you had stepped over the first (successful) evaluation, and then stepped into a failed one, you would have seen the code take the wrong path, and could have worked out why.

Comment: @MartinBonner: I strongly believe that beginners in C++ programming should use their debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You failed to initialize `ArithmeticExpression::isValue`.

```
ArithmeticExpression::ArithmeticExpression(std::string expr, bool isTopExpr) {
    this->isTopExpr = isTopExpr;
    int opIndex = findOpIndex(expr);
    resultStr = expr;
    if (opIndex == -1 || (opIndex == -1 && expr[0] == '-' && expr[1] != '(')) {
        isValue = true;
        arithExpr = NULL;
    } else {
        isValue = false; // add this line
        std::string leftExpr = expr.substr(0, opIndex);
        std::string rightExpr = expr.substr(opIndex+1, expr.length());
        arithExpr = new Addition(leftExpr, rightExpr);
    }
}
```

Also, I don't think accessing `expr[expr.length()]` is good and you should change

```
for (unsigned int c=expr.length(); c>0; c--) {
```

in `Expression.cpp` to

```
for (unsigned int c=expr.length()-1; c>0; c--) {
```

Comment: you have my most sincere gratitude @MikeCAT . :)